# Clean every item in an in Outlook Calendar which is scheduled after 2012?

Tags: outlook, calendar

A client of ours messed up a bunch of Outlook calendars. Is it possible to remove all stuff from an Outlook calendar after a certain date?

So item which takes place after 1-1-2012 gets deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind :-). It isn't possible.